# display date in cdetailsview in Yii

Tags: php, yii, cdetailview

I have the code below in view.php of a model:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'cat_id',
    'price',
            array(
                'name' => 'create_date',
                'header' => 'Create Date',
                'value' => 'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $data->create_date)'
            ),
    array(
                'name' => 'update_date',
                'header' => 'update Date',
                'value' => 'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $data->update_date)'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'last_visit_date',
                'header' => 'Last visit Date',
                'value' => 'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $data->last_visit_date)'
            ),
    'hit',
    'update_count',
    'status',
    'sold',
    'active',
),
```

)); ?>

but I see

```
Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $data->last_visit_date)
```

instead of converted date. I use this in admin.php and it is ok but in view.php it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete quotes, use this:

```
'value' => Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $model->last_visit_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete the quotes, because the CDetailView can only show one record. I think you also need to change $data to $model like this:

```
'value' => Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $model->create_date)
```

If you want to show multiple records, you can use [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)

**Note:**

In the CDetailView you're using a `CModel` as [data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#data-detail) and in the CListView you're using a `dataProvider`